# No right border for input field when suggesting as duplicate

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-questions

Right border of input field when suggesting closing a question as a duplicate isn't visible:

> [image: duplicate field]

Tested on Windows 7 for Firefox 64.0.2 and Chrome 71.0.3578.98

Comment: @Glorfindel did you see the issue when suggesting as duplicate? :)